# Passport radio option button redirecting to signup page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

[image]

If the user has the 'No' radio option button selected, how do I redirect to /signup?

**ROUTE**

```
// app/routes/users.js

app.post('/users/session', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/signin',
    failureFlash: true
}), users.session);
```

**VIEW**

```
<form action="/users/session" method="post">
  <input ng-change="change()" ng-model="NotSureWhatToPutHere" type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked> 
    <label for="optionsRadios1">
      No, I am a <b>new customer</b>.
    </label>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="NotSureWhatToPutHere" ng-change="change()" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
    <label class="control-label" for="optionsRadios2">
    Yes, I have a password:
    </label>
  <button type="submit">Sign in</button>   
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
// controllers/index.js

'use strict';

angular.module('mean.system').controller('IndexController', ['$scope', 'Global', function ($scope, Global) {
    $scope.global = Global;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much node/passport issue, it's an angular one.

I guess that you submit this with either angular (like, `$http.post('/users/session',...)` or you have a `<form action='/users/session' ...>`.

You need to tell angular that listens for the radio buttons (like, ng-change or something similar). When the user switches between no password and password, you should change your url to /signup.

So, no need to hit the server at all there. If you do want to proceed, you could add another middleware in there? Something like:

`app.post('/users/session', function(req, res, next) {
   if (req.body.youroptionselected) return res.redirect('/somewhere');
   next();
  }, .... other handler here)`
.

This would not redirect to POST /signup though - redirects never do.

Your Angular controller (client-side) example would be something like this:

```
angular.service('loginService', function($http){
    var service = {
        signin: function(email, password){
            $http.post('/users/session', {email: email, password: password})
            .success(function(response){
                // You're logged in here, you could do something like a redirect.
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('Something wen\'t wrong, show this message or something.');
            });
        }
        , signup: function(email) {
            $http.post('/signup', {email: email})
            .success(function(response){
                // You've handled this in your backend, now on the client you're in.
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('Something wen\'t wrong with signup., show this message or something.');
            });
        }
    }
})

angular.controller('loginController', function(loginService){
    // get a hold of the button here
    $scope.buttonClickHandler = function(){
        // if new user, use loginService.signup($scope.email)...
        // else use loginService.signin($scope.email, $scope.password) ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I added ng-change to the index.html. Is there a tutorial I can look to for more info on how to change the url without connecting to the server?

Comment: Uh, plenty of ways. Google or Stackoverflow search for "Javascript change form action" should help.
In the version you added, your $scope.change function should look like function() { /* if new customer, do something to action */}. But if you post your angular controller and a bit more of index.html, I can help a bit more.

Comment: Oh, no, I meant the angular controller. You know, the client-side javascript?

Comment: Freelancers always do :) Check my profile to get in touch.

Comment: Anyway, the mean stack you've linked to is a placeholder and a bit different from what your code is showing. Hope my advice can help you out.